# How to set the orientation of AVCaptureFileOutput?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I set the orientation of `AVCaptureFileOutput`? I mean the final output, it must be landscape.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup camera, you have a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput videoDataOutput, and a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer previewLayer. You can configure them in the following way.

```
//set the orientation of previewlayer, which is presented to user
AVCaptureConnection *conncetion = self.previewLayer.connection;
conncetion.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;

//set the output frame orientation
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
conn.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

In AVCam sample code, when recording and saving as a file. The above two are set to the same orientation, which is viewcontroller's interfaceOrientation:

```
[[[self movieFileOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];
```

And it observes device orientation, which is nice.